# Использование методов списка внутри функции print()

Tags: python, list, print, приоритет, порядок

Почему в примере

```py
fruits = ["яблоко", "банан", "вишня"]
print(fruits, fruits.pop())
```

в выводе я получаю:

```py
['яблоко', 'банан'] вишня
```

Почему не так:

```py
["яблоко", "банан", "вишня"] вишня
```

Ведь `fruits.pop()` следует после `fruits`.

Comment: Потому что функция print начинает выполняться уже после того, как выполнится fruits.pop(), а значит к тому моменту вишни внутри fruits уже не будет

Answer (score 2):

В принципе, ответ уже дан в комментарии, но всё же дополнительно поясню. Для этого покажу небольшой фокус:

```
fruits = ["яблоко", "банан", "вишня"]
print(fruits.copy(), fruits.pop())
```

Вывод:

```
['яблоко', 'банан', 'вишня'] вишня
```

Казалось бы: ну какая разница - использовать для печати список или его копию? А разница в том, что `fruits` - это фактически **ссылка** на список. Сначала `Python` собрал аргументы для функции - ссылку на список и собственно вынутый элемент списка, а потом он начал её выполнять. В моём варианте кода произошло копирование списка и `print` получил ссылку на копию (ещё целого) списка. А в вашем случае `print` получил ссылку на исходный список, в котором после выполнения `fruits.pop()` одного элемента уже не было к тому моменту, как начала выполняться сама функция `print` и она полезла в этот список за его элементами.